# Update JSON List object with PUT request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json response from my API when i invoke a methode i want to add new geolocation object to the list  with my current position using [geolocator pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)   the probleme in the IDE it's not showing anything but when i compile it it's generating this error
`Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used. "geolocation": planning.geolocation.add(buildClient(client, myPos)),`

## Planning API Response

```
{
   "id":3,
   "createdBy":"admin",
   "createdDate":1621779345.108107000,
   "lastModifiedBy":"admin",
   "lastModifiedDate":1621787873.353633000,
   "date":1621983600000,
   "type":"MORNING",
   "geolocation":[
      {
         "latitude":50.800810869328565,
         "longitude":70.13147767920817
      },
      {
         "latitude":123.800810869328565,
         "longitude":66.13147767920817
      }
   ],
   "done":true
}
```

## PUT Method

```
Future<void> checkVisite(Planning planning, int id) async {
var myPos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);


    var builder = json.encode({
      "id": planning.id,
      "createdBy": planning.createdBy,
      "createdDate": planning.createdDate,
      "lastModifiedBy": planning.lastModifiedBy,
      "lastModifiedDate": planning.lastModifiedDate,
      "date": planning.date,
      "type": planning.type,
      "geolocation": planning.geolocation.add(buildClient(myPos)),
      "done": planning.done
    });
    await crudHelper.update(
        DataCnst.planningENDPOINT + "/" + id.toString(), builder);
}

Geolocation buildClient(Position myPos) {
  Geolocation newItem;
  newItem.latitude = myPos.latitude;
  newItem.longitude = myPos.longitude;
  return newItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map strJson = {
      "id": planning.id,
      "createdBy": planning.createdBy,
      "createdDate": p`enter code here`lanning.createdDate,
      "lastModifiedBy": planning.lastModifiedBy,
      "lastModifiedDate": planning.lastModifiedDate,
      "date": planning.date,
      "type": planning.type,
      "geolocation": planning.geolocation.add(buildClient(myPos)),
      "done": planning.done
    }




Future<void> checkVisite(Planning planning, int id) async {
var myPos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

    Geolocation newItem;
    newItem.latitude = myPos.latitude;
    newItem.longitude = myPos.longitude;

    var builder = json.encode(strJson);
    await crudHelper.update(
        DataCnst.planningENDPOINT + "/" + id.toString(), builder);
}
```